# Heroku not implementing latest pushes from github repo in deploy

Tags: heroku, github

I have three different apps I have set up on heroku. When I run the apps, the apps show up in the browser, but they are very old versions of the apps.

I have configured each project to deploy a new build everytime changes are pushed to the linked github repos, and the activity feed claims the builds are successful. The logs also don't appear to show any errors.

I also know heroku is receiving the pushes because it is running new builds when I push and when I monitor the "see diff", the changes are displayed.

I am at a total loss as to what is going on and it's very frustrating. If nothing else, does anyone have any suggestions for similar services to heroku that do not have so many deploy issues?

Answer (score 1):

Try and make sure heroku has the latest, from a local GitHub repo clone:

```
 cd /path/to/my/local/clone
 git remote add heroku /url/heroku/repo
 git push --force heroku HEAD:master
```

That will make sure there is no "detached HEAD" situation on the heroku side, which would explain why the push does not update the working tree.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (the slug that had been built suddenly was too large, 589 MB). Heroku still got notified when new commits were pushed to my GitHub repository, but it always used old files and never the latest ones (using a different branch and disconnecting/connecting GitHub again didn't change anything).

First I tried the following steps:

#### Purging the build cache

You could try to purge the build cache using the following CLI command:

`heroku builds:cache:purge -a <your-app-name-here>`

#### Checking the contents of your slug

If purging the build cache doesn't work, you can investigate what is really contained in your slug. To do this, you can use the [Heroku Slugs CLI Plugin](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-slugs) by first installing it:

`heroku plugins:install heroku-slugs`

and then querying your slugs with:

`heroku slugs -a <your-app-name-here>`

which should result in an output similar to this:

```
Slugs in <your-app-name-here>
v107: 00000000-1c6e-45ce-8899-b0e0d047ded1
v106: 11111111-73b1-4cf6-81af-b622d08ac523
v105: 22222222-cab8-40df-b6ce-d22398dfdeec
v104: 33333333-df6c-4051-bf63-b851fc13946d
...
```

Then download the latest one (in the example it would be `v107`) with:

`heroku slugs:download 00000000-1c6e-45ce-8899-b0e0d047ded1 -a <your-app-name-here>`

You can then look through the folder and verify which versions of files were used from your repositories (in my case it turned out, that the files were indeed not the most recent ones).

#### Contact support

In my case the next step was to open a support ticket. They temporarily raised the allowed size for slugs to 600 MB which allowed me to build the slug with the larger size.

Once that was done I initiated a second deployment which - according to their support - removed stale files from the slug and the size also dropped significantly to only about ~185 MB.